# Not able to login into tomcat 7 even after setting login credentials into tomcat-users.xml file

Tags: tomcat7

I have installed tomcat 7 on windows 7.I want to deploy .war file.After going through few blogs and webpages related to login into tomcat manager i made changes into conf/tomcat-users.xml file and it now it looks like as follows:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='cp1252'?>
<!--
  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
  contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
  this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
  The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
  (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
  the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
-->
<tomcat-users>
<!--
  NOTE:  By default, no user is included in the "manager-gui" role required
  to operate the "/manager/html" web application.  If you wish to use this app,
  you must define such a user - the username and password are arbitrary.
-->
<!--
  NOTE:  The sample user and role entries below are wrapped in a comment
  and thus are ignored when reading this file. Do not forget to remove
  <!.. ..> that surrounds them.
-->
<!--
  <role rolename="tomcat"/>
  <role rolename="role1"/>
  <role rolename="admin"/>
  <role rolename="manager"/>

  <user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat"/>
  <user username="both" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat,role1"/>
  <user username="role1" password="tomcat" roles="role1"/>
-->
<role rolename="tomcat"/>
  <role rolename="role1"/>
  <role rolename="admin"/>
  <role rolename="manager"/>
  <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
  <user username="abc" password="abc" roles="manager-gui,admin,manager,tomcat,role1"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

Then i restarted localhost:8080 and there clicked on manager app button which then shows login screen and i typed login details(abc) as present in .xml file above.But still I am not able to login.What I need to do to login successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I use standard tomcat roles and it works. Try to use them. 
To deploy a war-file you need only manager-gui role.

```
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
    <role rolename="manager-script"/>
    <role rolename="manager-jmx"/>
    <role rolename="admin-gui"/>
    <role rolename="admin-script"/>
    <user username="root" password="root" roles="standard, manager-gui, manager-script, manager-jmx, admin-gui, admin-script"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing the port from 8080 to 8088 in server.xml worked for me.refer the code below

```
    <Connector port="8088" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
    connectionTimeout="20000"
    redirectPort="8443" />
```